# MPLAB unable to combine .s and .c files

Tags: c, assembly, error-handling, mplab, xc16

I am using MPLAB v4.0.5 on my Mac, with the XC16 v1.33 compiler. I have two files, thom5409_disc2_main_v001.s and thom5409_disc2_main_v001.c .

The following code was provided to help get us started and other students in my class were able to get the same exact code to build with no changes, so I believe it is an issue with my version of MPLAB or the compiler.

So basically, my assembly code looks like this:
[image: AssemblyCode]

And my c code looks like this
[image]

When I try to build it, I get the following errors:

`multiple definition of '_counter'` and
`multiple definition of '_myAsmFunc'`

When I remove the lines in the assembly file that say
`.global _myAsmFunc` and
`.global _counter`

I get the following errors instead:
`undefined reference to '_main'` and
`undefined reference to '_myGlobalVar'`

I have tried debugging and figuring out a solution to this, but I can't seem to figure it out. As mentioned before, other classmates using various machines and versions of both MPLAB and the XC compiler were able to get it to work, so I don't believe it is a code issue, but maybe I have to change the code a little bit for MPLAB or the compiler?

Comment: Please post code as text. My compiler has no [OCR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition) ability, nor can I copy/paste to a text editor

Answer (score 4):

Both files will be compiled to `thom5409_disc2_main_v001.o`. What you should do is rename one of the files so that the .c and .s files get compiled to different object files.